# PostGIS: Linestring length

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, postgis

I am using PostGIS to calculate length of a user-defined linestring. The column is defined as `geography(LineString,4326)`.
The linestring is represented by this GeoJSON:

```
"track": {
  "type": "LineString",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      49.364325571013,
      16.785549033597
    ],
    [
      49.363254969491,
      16.642149334451
    ]
  ]
}
```

`SELECT ST_Length("geography") FROM table;` returns 15945.7486086962 but the length measured on Google Maps is ~10 km.

What am I doing wrong? How to measure the length to get the same value as from Google Maps?

Comment: Hey Andrej. Could you also show how you got the 10km length using google maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is the classic issue of switching *x,y* positions.

Considering *x,y*:

```
SELECT 
    ST_Length(
      ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(49.364325571013 16.785549033597,49.363254969491 16.642149334451)'),true);

    st_length     
------------------
 15869.9069442778
```

and the "same" LineString switching to *y,x* ..

```
SELECT 
   ST_Length(
     ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(16.785549033597 49.364325571013,16.642149334451 49.363254969491)'),true)

    st_length     
------------------
 10416.8606521809
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem.

I was using `ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(lat lon, lat lon)')` to create the line. The correct order is `lon lat`, so `ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(lon lat, lon lat)')`.

GeoJSON uses the same order of coordinates: 49.363254969491 = latitude, 16.642149334451 = longitude.

The reason I didn't realize this was because I used Leaflet to draw the line. I basically took the points by `geoJSON.getLayers()[0].feature.geometry.coordinates` and passed them to a Polyline object. It created the Polyline points by taking the first coordinate from the GeoJSON as Lat, the second as Lng. This way it got reversed the second time and got rendered correctly.

So after switching lon lat in the query I had to use `L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs()` function to correctly render the line.